# executing an event based on another event

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I'm developing an c# winform application which saves the mouse click co-ordinates anywhere in the screen. I don't want to save the co-ordinate when the mouse clicks on the minimized icon on the taskbar to restore the form. I have raised a event while form resizing happens, to store the window state and check the state before saving the co-ordinates in the mouse_click event. But the mouse-click occurs first and its not reading the window state which occurs after the mouse-click..please help me how to make the mouse-click event read the window state after mouse click on the task bar happened.

thanks.

Comment: What is the form's size and is it visible?

Comment: You could create an invisible form which is the size of the screen and gets the coordinates on mousehover and returns it to the other form : that would not include the taskbar.

Comment: i want to perform some actions on the form which wont be saved. Rephrasing my question, i need to save all the mouse coordinates except those clicking on the forms.I was able to achieve this by saving the co-ordinates only when the form is not active. but it doesnt work while restoring the form because at the instance of restoring click, the form inactive, so its saving the co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can think of is this according to your comment. This saves the mouse X in a list, and the same with the Y. I haven't included the namespaces, as you can add this into your form code anyway. You can use CreateSensor(); to create the sensor, and Analyse(); to analyse the X and Y values.

```
public void CreateSensor(){
    Form SensorForm = new Form();
    SensorForm.Visible = false;
    SensorForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    SensorForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; 
    SensorForm.MouseHover += new MouseEventHandler(SensorForm_Hover);
}

var MouseXList = new List<int>();   
var MouseYList = new List<int>();   

public void Analyse(){
    if(MouseXList.Count != MouseYList.Count){
        Console.WriteLine("An error occured when collection the mouse coordinates");
         return;      
    } 
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < MouseXList.Count; ++i){
            Console.WriteLine("X: {0}, Y: {1}\n", MouseXList[i].ToString(), MouseYList[i].ToString());
        } 
    } 
}

private void SensorForm_Hover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
     MouseXList.Add(e.X);
     MouseYList.Add(e.Y);       
}
```

If it doesn't work, tell me, and I will try and fix it for you